# Need a VBA code for autotext from dropdown menu

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing a code to select a specific autotext from a dropdown list. I've not written code since the late 1970s the old Basic A...I've forgotten most of it.

The dropdown list is called HVAC
the text to insert is in an autotext file called "Split Systems"  or whichever text associated with the dropdown items
The error message is "5941 the requested member of the collection does not exist"

I've tried using the value of 1,2,3,or 4 in the if statement line instead of the "Split...", it doesn't work either

Where is issue or how should I code it.

MY code follows:

```vb
    Sub one()

    If ActiveDocument.Formfields(hvac).DropDown.Value = "Split Systems" Then GoTo 10 Else GoTo 20

    10
    ActiveDocument.Content.Select  
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Split Systems").Insert _
    Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
    GoTo 100
    20

    If ActiveDocument.Formfields(hvac).DropDown.Value = "Packaged Systems" Then GoTo 25 Else GoTo 30
 
    25
    ActiveDocument.Content.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Packaged System").Insert _
    Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
    GOto 100
    30

    If ActiveDocument.Formfields(hvac).DropDown.Value = Central Heating System" Then GoTo 35 Else GoTo 40

    35
    ActiveDocument.Content.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Central Heating System").Insert _
    Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
    GoTo 100
    40
    If ActiveDocument.Formfields(hvac).DropDown.Value = "PTACs" Then GoTo 45
    45
    ActiveDocument.Content.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Central Heating System").Insert _
    Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True

    100

    End Sub
```

Tried everything I know

Comment: I see you are using legacy formfields. Look into Content Controls. In general they are both more powerful and more flexible. They should not, however, be mixed with Content Controls.

Comment: « Look into Content Controls. In general they are both more powerful and more flexible.» Using content controls for the OP's purposes necessitates the use of VBA. By comparison, the same results with formfields can be achieved without it - simply by embedding what is now the Autotext content in an IF field that tests the Dropdown's status and setting the dropdown's 'Calculate on Exit' property. Content Controls and *Formfields* should not be used in the same document.

Comment: macropod's comment is correct when you want a remote response to a choice, rather than simply pulling up the AutoText in the dropdown location. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Word now has **Building Block Gallery Content Controls** that eliminate the need to add code to dropdowns. Choose the **Developer** tab, then choose *Building Block Gallery Content Control* in the Controls group. Use the **Properties** button in the Controls group to point the control at *AutoText*. The only significant drawback is that this control doesn't currently work in Word for Mac.

Comment: Does it not work, or does it only work for AutoText? The AutoTextList field still does work on the Mac.

Comment: Hi Charles, It doesn't work at all on a Mac. In Windows, the title bar of the control includes a dropdown to allow you to choose the entry to insert. That dropdown doesn't appear on a Mac, so there is no way to select anything.

Answer (score 0):

***Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?***

### Look at AutoTextList and Building Blocks Gallery Content Control

These two features built into Word create drop downs of AutoText or other Building Blocks. What are you trying to do that cannot be accomplished using one of them?

Here is my writing on the [Building Blocks Gallery Content Control](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#BBGalleryContentControl).

Here is a link to a [sample template with both](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#BuildingBlockGalleryContentControlAutoTextList).

The Content Control gives a very nice drop-down gallery.

[image: building blocks gallery control screen shot]

Here is a link to [vba to insert AutoText/Building Blocks](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock). *(It varies depending on the location of the AutoText.)*

Note: all links are to my writing.

Comment: Thanks for all the info but what I'm trying to do is use a dropdown list in the executive summary of my report, make a selection from the list, that one word selection goes into a chart in the executive summary, then pending on which selection I make, it automatically writes a specific paragraph (found in an autotext file) about that selection several pages later in my report.  There will be about 20 differing dropdown lists, each with 4 to 5 options, and each will go into a differing section of my report.  Each rept is about 50 to 100 pages. (I have +- 200 autotext files)

Comment: I did not understand that you wanted the AutoText at a remote location. See my new answer below. Paul Edstein @macropod is correct that to do this without macros you must use a legacy form field rather than Content Controls. While I prefer CCs,  the coding to handle this with them is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Field Coding rather than vba for this

Since you want to select something in your list and have the AutoText appear in a different location in the document, this could be done with either an AutoText field or with an IF Field.

The AutoText Field would only be useful if what is in your dropdown is the exact name of an AutoText entry's name. This is unlikely.

However, the AutoText Field could be combined in an IF Field that tests the choice in the dropdown.

Here is an example where the choice in the dropdown is "Choice 1," the bookmark name of the Dropdown is "Location" and the corresponding AutoText entry is named "TextPart123."

The properties in your dropdown must include Calculate on Exit checked. [image]

```
{ IF { Location } = "Choice 1" "{ AutoText TextPart123 }" }
```

For the dropdown to work, that part of the document must be protected for filling in forms.

Here is a [temporary link to a sample document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbfnxoji0uvoikd/deleteme%20dropdown%20for%20conditional%20autotext.docx?dl=0) with a dropdown and fields like the one above. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbfnxoji0uvoikd/deleteme%20dropdown%20for%20conditional%20autotext.docx?dl=0
The first two choices trigger different building blocks. The third choice does not trigger anything.

**To trigger the change, you need to exit from the dropdown.** Typically this is done using the Tab key.

*Note that because there are currently no AutoText entries built into Word, the AutoText field in the sample calls a couple of Watermarks that are built in. The field works with any Building Block, including AutoText.*

---

If you absolutely need to use vba to insert AutoText rather than use the AutoText field, see my page on Boilerplate in Word, specifically on using [vba to insert building blocks](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock). As you've discovered, with the entry of Building Blocks in 2007 the code to insert became finicky.